# Passport Authenticate with Google reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, recaptcha

I'm trying to incorporate google reCaptcha to my signup form's back-end that already has passport authentication on it the code looks like this:

```
    app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs', { 
            message : req.flash('signupMessage')
        });
    });

    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/app', // redirect to the secure chat section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

And this is my google recaptha code:

```
    app.get('/signup', recaptcha.middleware.render, function(req, res) {
        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs', { 
            message : req.flash('signupMessage'),
            captcha : req.recaptcha
        });
    });

   app.post('/signup', recaptcha.middleware.verify, function(req, res){
        if (!req.recaptcha.error) {
            //if recaptcha is correct do somthing
        }else {
            req.flash('signupMessage','reCAPTCHA Incorrect');
            res.redirect('/signup');
        }
    });
```

Both work independently, But when I combine them like this:

```
    app.get('/signup', isNotLoggedIn, recaptcha.middleware.render, function(req, res) {
        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs', { 
            message : req.flash('signupMessage'),
            captcha : req.recaptcha
        });
    });

    app.post('/signup', recaptcha.middleware.verify, function(req, res){
        if (!req.recaptcha.error) {
            passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
                successRedirect : '/app', 
                failureRedirect : '/signup',
                failureFlash : true
            });
        }else {
            req.flash('signupMessage','reCAPTCHA Incorrect');
            res.redirect('/signup');
        }
    });
```

Or this:

```
    app.get('/signup', isNotLoggedIn, recaptcha.middleware.render, function(req, res) {
        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs', { 
            message : req.flash('signupMessage'),
            captcha : req.recaptcha
        });
    });

    app.post('/signup', recaptcha.middleware.verify, function(req, res){
        if (req.recaptcha.error) {
            req.flash('signupMessage','reCAPTCHA Incorrect');
            res.redirect('/signup');
        }
    },
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/app', // redirect to the secure chat section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

The page stays on loading and nothing happends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out!

The trick is on using the next(); function if captcha is correct so the code ends up like this:

```
    app.get('/signup', isNotLoggedIn, recaptcha.middleware.render, function(req, res) {
        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs', { 
            message : req.flash('signupMessage'),
            captcha : req.recaptcha
        });
    });

    app.post('/signup', recaptcha.middleware.verify, captchaVerification, passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/app', // redirect to the secure chat section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));

function captchaVerification(req, res, next) {
    if (req.recaptcha.error) {
        req.flash('signupMessage','reCAPTCHA Incorrect');
        res.redirect('/signup');
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}
```

And thats how you integrate google captcha to your nodejs, express, passport, back-end